# Unable to do HTTP post in Python

Tags: python, http, post

I'm trying to configure an Access Point(AP) in my office through HTTP Post method via Python.

I was able to login to the AP through Python HTTP Authentication code but when I click on wireless page of the AP to give inputs such as AP SSID, Channel and Passphrase, I'm getting stuck at this point. There is a apply button at the end of the wireless page.

When I'm trying to do that using the below mentioned code, I don't see any changes getting reflected at the AP side. May be my code is wrong or I'm not following the correct procedure to post the data in the AP. How can I resolve this issue?

```
import urllib2
import requests

def login():
        link = "http://192.168.1.11/start_apply2.htm"
        username = 'admin'
        password = 'admin'
        p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        p.add_password(None, link, username, password)
        handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        age = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
        payload = {'wl_ssid_org': 'nick','wl_wpa_psk_org':12345678}
        r = requests.get(link)
        r = requests.get(link, params=payload)
        r = requests.post(link, params=payload)
login()
```

Note: When I'm running this code, it was throwing error as: 401 unauthorized. When I'm able to login to the AP using same auth code but why I'm unable to clear the authentication here, I'm not getting it.

Comment: An AP that requires basic auth as the only security measure would be a great security risk. So I guess there are more security feature, like a XSRF cookie, a session or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should change

```
r = requests.post(link, params=payload)
```

to

```
r = requests.post(link, data=payload)
```

Then you can do the POST request successfully.

You should refer to the [requests document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) to find more tutorials.

Even, you can replace the code using `urllib2` with code using `requests`.

Comment: hi, I have tried even with data i.e.., r = requests.post(link, data=payload) but its not working...

Comment: Then the problem might be that you fail to get the authorization.
You should try to figure out what kind of authorization it needs